# How to create a menu with data's in the database in Django

Tags: django, html, django-templates

To create a menu for this class and when selected it gives the value of rent to a variable

```
class Venues(models.Model):
    venue_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rent = models.IntegerField()
    parking_area = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: well, i think you should give us some html as example that what you expect, no?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: no i haven't tried menu i wanted is something like this http://0.s3.envato.com/files/25057600/Preview.jpg when i click the sublink it should give the value rent to particular variable